# Prove or disprove: Let R be an Euclidean domain, then $I= \{a\in R\mid \delta(a)>\delta(1_R)\}$ is an ideal in R.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove:

> Let R be an Euclidean domain, then
> $I= \{a\in R\mid \delta(a)>\delta(1_R)\}$ is an ideal in R.

I showed that $I$ has the superclosure property because of the property of euclidean domain $\delta(ab) \geq \delta(a)$ so I thought that $I$ should be an ideal However according to the solution manual, the answer is actually false and they claim it is false for even $Z$. However I don't see how that could be possible unless the product of two elements in I is a unit, but the only units are 1 and -1 and they are not in $I$ and all the other elements don't have inverses.

Comment: I may be forgetting, but I don’t think $\alpha$ and $\delta$ are standard notations. Can you define them?

Comment: Is $I$ closed under addition?

Comment: @ yes I is closed under addition. it is an ideal.

Comment: Also, i need to make some edits. I accidentally changed symbols.

Comment: Wait, what does $>$ mean in $R,$ then?

Comment: William, what book are you using? Also, a link to the lecture notes  please

Comment: @WillJagy the text is hungerford, an introduction to abstract algebra, third edition chapter 10.1 on euclidean domains. problem 28

Comment: Asserting it is an ideal is not the same as proving it. Is $0\in I?$ Certainly, if $a\in I, $ then $-a\in I$ so $a+(-a)\in I.$ But $\delta(0)>\delta(1)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is not in $I,$ and $0$ is in every ideal.

If you manually also add $0$ to $I$ the theorem is true for some Euclidean domains. The $p$-adic integers are an ED, and $I\cup\{0\}$ is an ideal there.

$p$-adic integers have only one prime.

In the case of $\mathbb Z,$ we have $3,-2\in I,$ but $3+(-2)\notin I.$

If you add $0$ by definition to $I,$ though, in most usual cases you will have $I$ not closed under addition.

In Euclidean domains, any ideal is a principal ideal. So if $I\cup \{0\}$ is an ideal, there must be an $r$ such that $I\cup \{0\}=rR.$ Now. Show that $r$ must have only one prime divisor. (Because all non-unit divisors of $r$ which are must be in $I$.) If $R$ has a second prime, $q,$ then $q\in I$ so $r$ is a divisor of $q.$

So. it can be true in an ED only when it has only one prime. A ring with only one maximal ring is called a local ring, but in Euclidean domains, a maximal ideal is just the principal ideal of a prime.

You can show the other direction so: A Euclidean domain $R$ has $I\cup \{0\}$ an ideal if and only if $R$ is also a local ring.

Comment: Being undefined at $0$ means it is not true that $\delta(0)>\delta(1).$ @william